Any subgraph-like tools on Solana?
I am building a Dapp, and want to get the transactions of user deposits/withdrawal etc, and do some data engineering like how Subgraph is used for EVM. Is there any tools for the Solana ecosystem?

You can look at specialized RPC providers like Helius, which provide additional indexing on top of the normal account data

Subgraphs are currently supported for Solana on The Graph, can see it here: https://thegraph.com/networks/
You can reach out to the teams involved either through The Graph discord or StreamingFast discord (one of the engineering teams).
